# check if file exists and if its file is not 0

Tags: perl

I noticed that some scripts I'm revisioning are full of

```
if (-e $fullpath_err and -s $fullpath_err > 0) {
 ...
```

where `$fullpath_err` is an `absolute file path`.
I want to lean the condition.

I thought to create a `sub` like this:

```
sub fileIsValid {
  my $filepath = shift;
  return (-e $filepath and -s $filepath > 0);
}
```

and use it this way:

```
if (fileIsValid($fullpath_err)) {
 ...
```

Is there another (maybe simpler) way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One small optimisation. The `-e` and `-s` calls will both make a `stat` call to the underlying operating system. This can add a small overhead to your code. Each `stat` call will actually return all of the data about the file, so calling it twice is wasteful. But Perl caches the data from the more recent `stat` against the special filehandle `_`, so if you use that instead of the filename on your second call, you'll save one call to `stat`.

```
sub fileIsValid {
  my $filepath = shift;
  return (-e $filepath and -s _ > 0);
}
```

**Note:** I've also removed the unnecessary and potentially problematic prototype.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there another (maybe simpler) way to do this?

Not really, as far as I know.  Your code is good, idomatic Perl.  You can prototype `fileIsValid()` if you like, so that it will specifically take a single, scalar argument:

```
sub fileIsValid ($) {
  my $filepath = shift;
  return (-e $filepath and -s $filepath > 0);
}
```

Even the prototype is probably unnecessary, though.

Your code is good.

Answer (score -1):

If the file does not exist, then it has no size. All that is really needed is:

if ( -s $fullpath_err ) {
    ...